# JavaFX hide text of column in tableview

Tags: text, javafx, hide, tableview

I have a tableview and I want to show an image in the first column. My problem is I can't sort the column then. My idea is to set text in the column too and hide the text so it is only for the correct sorting set. Is there a way to do that? Or what other solutions are possible for my problem?

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you're doing? You should just be setting a cell factory to display an image: that won't prevent sorting.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at:

- [`TableColumn.setCellValueFactory()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellValueFactory(javafx.util.Callback))
  Provides the actual cell value (used for sorting!).
- [`TableColumn.setCellFactory()`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory(javafx.util.Callback))
  Provides the rendering.

In other words: If you need the sort order, you must not change the content, but only the Cell rendering. The methods mentioned above let you do exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the perfect example what you wants to do.Still let me know if you have any issue.
[Check here](http://blog.ngopal.com.np/2011/10/01/tableview-cell-modifiy-in-javafx/)

Answer (score -3):

You could do it with just CSS using text-indent. You would also need to set the image as a css background. You did not provide an code of your table, but below is some example:

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1">
  <tr>
    <td class="hidetext image">Text 1</td>
    <td>Some text to show</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidetext image">Text 2</td>
    <td>Some text to show</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidetext image">Text 3</td>
    <td>Some text to show</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="hidetext image">Text 4</td>
    <td>Some text to show</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
.hidetext {text-indent:-9000px}
.image {background:url(http://www.madisoncopy.com/images/jpeg.jpg) no-repeat;}
```

See how in the left column the text does not show (but it is actually there just indented off the screen).

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D297P/

Comment: This answer is wrong.  The question is about JavaFX, it is not related to HTML.